# How to use matrices to solve a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm quite confused on using this matrix equation to find the voltage across the 3ohm resistor. Once I fill in the values of the resistors for the Y values where Y=1/Z I get stuck. I'm not quite sure how to continue with it any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. I have to use the given matrix equations in the form YV = I

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like nodal analysis, except that your current sources appear to have volts as their units. (I didn't check everything though.) To solve using matrix math you multiply the left side using the inverse of the 4x4 matrix placed to the far left. And do the same to the right side, also placing the inverse to the left. So \$Y^{-1} Y V=Y^{-1}I\$. Then just perform the right side multiplication. Or by hand use Cramer's Rule.

Comment: @jonk I've seen that before where the voltage sources are depicted by a polarity arrow which makes them look *really* similar to current sources of other conventions. If the arrow isn't inside the circle and especially if it has voltage units, it's a voltage source.I've seen at least two problems on SE previously that were held up because of that. I don't know what countries are using that symbol but I freakin' hate it.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah. I dislike those symbols, too. But the matrices and arrays the OP shows us suggest a four node situation with nodal analysis, from my cursory view. That might hold water, but what doesn't make sense to me is **I**, where the OP shows \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ which I take to be ***currents*** and not ***voltages***. If they are current sources and not voltage sources then at least the first row makes sense to me. But that would mean they are currents, not voltages. But the labeling says **V**. So I'm just confused.

Comment: @jonk I can try to solve it. I really should get better at nodal analysis but I've never needed it over mesh. Got nothing but time now anyways. Recovering from jaw surgery and just go to the point where I can breathe and sleep aka focus. Which means I also finally have time to go through Matters and Interactions.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh cool! Matter & Interactions is a very pleasant read. Best wishes on the jaw, of course. I'm hoping for few (\$\ll 1\$) complications there. It sounds as though the OP cannot use a computer, either. So this probably means Cramer's Rule, if it has to be by hand (unless the OP enjoys sitting down and playing around adding/subtracting rows to diagonalize **Y** while tracking changes to **I**.)

Comment: @jonk Well, second jaw surgery so it in itself is already a complication. I tried it as voltage sources. Only needed two nodal equations though so I'm not sure why there are four.  They resemble rows 2 and 3. Also, fountain pens are awesome. I wish I knew about these when I was in school.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's because the OP's equations are assuming that \$V_1\$ and \$V_4\$ are unknown, despite the fact that they are known.

Comment: @jonk Ohhhhh. I see what you mean about the current sources now. Yeah. The first and fourth row don't make sense if those two sources are actually voltage sources. If they are voltage sources you only need two nodal equations. If they are current sources then you need four. Trust the matrix or trust the schematic. The easy way out would be to trust the schematic but it's more likely that the schematic is wrong since it's a much smaller change to correct it than the matrix.

Comment: @DKNguyen No. That's not it. Let me post something quickly, which I'll later finish. You'll get it very quickly once you see it. (That was my first thought, though. I've just realized I was wrong, before.)

Comment: I have to "eat" now anyways. Every few hours. Like a baby.

Comment: @DKNguyen Cripes. Broth? Anyway, I added something to look at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120902/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-jonk).

Answer (score 4):

The schematic, if I'm reading your problem correctly, is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fba73Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I'm right then you happen to know, a priori, two of the node voltages. But let's say, for now, that we want to write out the nodal equations for all four nodes:

$$\begin{array}{ccccl}
V_1\cdot G_1&-V_2\cdot G_1&+V_3\cdot 0&+V_4\cdot 0&=I_1\\
-V_1\cdot G_1 &+ V_2\cdot\left(G_1+G_2+G_3\right)&-V_3\cdot G_3&+V_4\cdot 0&=0\:\text{A}\\
V_1\cdot 0 &-V_2\cdot G_3 &+ V_3\cdot\left(G_3+G_4+G_5\right)&-V_4\cdot G_5 &= 0\:\text{A}\\
V_1\cdot 0 &+V_2\cdot 0&-V_3\cdot G_5&+V_4\cdot G_5&=-I_2
\end{array}$$

This is the same as:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
G_1&-G_1&0&0\\
-G_1 &G_1+G_2+G_3&-G_3& 0\\
0 &-G_3 & G_3+G_4+G_5&-G_5\\
0 &0&-G_5&G_5
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}V_1\\V_2\\V_3\\V_4\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\\0\:\text{A}\\0\:\text{A}\\-I_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

You already know \$V_1\$ and \$V_4\$, so this becomes:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
\frac12\:\text{S}&-\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}\\
-\frac12\:\text{S} &\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&-\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\:\text{S}\\
0\:\text{S} &-\frac16\:\text{S} & \frac35\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}\\
0\:\text{S} &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&\frac1{10}\:\text{S}
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}8\:\text{V}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-1\:\text{V}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\0\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\0\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

So, this is four equations in four unknowns. Do you know how to re-arrange it and then solve?

One step is to get all the unknowns in the same column-array. You can do this easily by pulling the unknowns to the left. So, verify that you can see how to re-arrange it this way:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

Once you are here, you can use any or all of the usual methods of hand-solutions. These include Cramer's Rule or diagonalizing the left side matrix, etc. Lots of ways to go.

Of course, the canonical way to go is this:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\\\\\therefore\\\\
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]
$$

---

It's been two days, now. So I may as well provide the detailed solution for others to consider:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\frac12\:\text{S}&0\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &-\frac{11}{12}\:\text{S}&\frac16\:\text{S}& 0\\
0 &\frac16\:\text{S} & -\frac35\:\text{S}&0\\
0 &0\:\text{S}&-\frac1{10}\:\text{S}&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\-4\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\frac1{10}\:\text{A}\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\\\\\therefore\\\\
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\V_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\V_3\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\I_2\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{323}{188}\\\\ \frac{429}{94}\\\\ \frac{207}{188}\\\\ \frac{79}{376}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\approx \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1.71808510638298\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\ 4.56382978723404\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\ 1.10106382978723\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\\\\ 0.210106382978723\phantom{\frac{11}{12}}\end{smallmatrix}\right]
$$

Comment: Oh, I see. You didn't mean they may have been current sources leading to unknown V1 and V4. You just meant that if V1 and V4 were unknown you then you would have 4 equations. Even if they were voltage sources which were unknown.

Comment: @DKNguyen Okay. I have time for chat, now. If you want, anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm just kind of here

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the matrices for now.

Write our your mesh equations for each loop. Each equation will have one term in it representing a net voltage source within the loop which may or may not be zero. All other terms will be IZ.

Now you want to solve these equations simultaneously and matrices are just a mindless way to do that.

So you first have to makes all the equations of the same form as each other so they fit into the matrix. In other words, make all the equations have the same terms by adding on terms to each equation that are present in other equations set I to zero for the terms that do not apply. That makes all the equations have all the same terms even if they are not applicable.

Then put those coefficients into the matrix and solve it. One column represents the net voltage, all other columnns represent the current through a particular Z. Then you row-reduce the matrix to solve it. The matrix is just a convenient way to solve simultaneous equations in this case.

Comment: The question says to utilise the matrix equation shown in the form YV = I  so should I still just make a new one?

Comment: @Kelko It's a bit weird becuase they gave you the form of the matrix that represents the circuit but not the specific matrix you need since none of the terms are explicitly labelled as anything from your circuit. So you either have to figure out what components from the circuit matches the terms in their matrix or just make your own matrix from scratch.

Comment: Ohhhh it just clicked on my head thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: @Kelko But if you make you own matrix, it won't match up up with the form that they have given unless you happen to pick the exact same current loops and directions. They seem to have used 4 loop equations (the fourth one probably being a redundant supermesh around the outside) when you only really need 3. I am not sure why they did that.

Comment: see the matrix form that they give is found using the same circuit but using current sources instead of voltage sources and then they used nodal analysis to get the equations

Comment: @Kelko Ah okay. That's why it looks so strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Y*V=I . Here you know Y and I.  Often what you would like to know is V, which is all the voltages at the nodes of the circuit.  So, you solve this equation for V.  To solve a matrix equation like this, it is easiest to use a computer program (like Matlab).

Kelko: Oh, my bad!!! I did not pay attention to this problem.  It is really a trick question, since the equations given are not really applicable to this circuit.  Sorry.

In this circuit, ask yourself what you know and what you want to know. There are four nodes in the circuit, but there are not four unknowns in this problem!  In fact, you already know one node voltage is 8v and one node voltage is -1v. So, you will need to find two equations that will allow you to solve for v2 and v3, the two unknowns. No use writing kircoffs current law at the nodes with the voltage sources, because there is no way you can determine the currents that these sources may be generating.  The two equations that you need are kircoffs current law at the the v2 and v3 nodes.  So, this is not a problem with 4 equations in 4 unknowns, it is a problem with two equations in two unknowns. ( easy to solve without a computer)

Comment: I can’t use a computer program and I don’t know what I Is. Tbh if i knew how to find the two I values then I’d be able to solve the rest of the equation easily

Comment: even with 2 equations though I'm not too sure how I'm supposed to solve them using the matrix equations. I understand making the equations and putting them into the matrix but past that I have no idea. Especially because the questions says that I have to utilise the matrix given.

Comment: @Kelko Do you know what row reduced echelon form is? You blindly do that (a mathematician could tell you why it works but you can sort of feel why it works when you do it manually). And all the forms of the equations are still the same. After you get your new matrix, the form of the equations is still the same as when you first put them in as when you first moved them into a matrix. So now take them back out and write the equations based on the coefficients and numbers in your new matrix. What do those new equations say?

Comment: @Kelko https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST1qx.png

Answer (score 0):

If \$YV = I\$ is your given system, and you are looking for the currents through the resistors (=vector \$I\$) you simply have to multiply matrix \$Y\$ by vector \$V\$ (given voltages).

When you know the current through the resistor, you get the voltage across by Ohm's law.

Comment: we aren't given the voltages for all of the nodes we only know V1 = 8V and V4 = -1V the rest I don't know

Comment: yes, you are right, not *all* voltages of \$V\$ are given; but on the other hand two currents of the current vector \$I\$ are given (both are 0). Basically that makes it not more difficult. Still 4 linear equations, with 4 unknowns (2 voltages, 2 currents); use Gaussean Elimination to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix equation is what most of the circuit calculation software use to solve circuits. It's derived from the KCL with application of Ohm's law to substitute \$I_{ab} = 1/Z_{ab}(V_a-V_b)\$ for all branches with impedance. One node is usually selected as "ground" where voltage is zero and so you have no equation for it, but have admittance to ground in the diagonal elements of the matrix. If a circuit has current sources they are accounted in the KCL. If a circuit has a voltage source, it's not an issue because the voltage source produce some current, so we just treat the current as unknown and write the KCL anyway.

Back to your problem.

You may notice that in your equations the 2nd and the 3rd may be solved separately to find \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$. System of two equations is easy to solve by hand. Then you may as well solve the rest of the equations to find \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$.

What happens is you effectively replace your left and right source with their Norton's equivalents to get a simple circuit with two unknown voltages.